# feynman package - where to put the feynman.sty file?

Tags: packages

I am using Bakoma-Tex 11.41 and I am trying to use the `feynman` package to draw some Feynman diagrams.

My problem is that I don't know where to put the `feynman.sty` file? in which directory?

I tried putting it in both of the next directories:

```
bakoma/local/tex/latex
```

and in the directory where all the typed TeX files of mine are, but it doesn't seem to be working, so where to put it?

Comment: Hm, Bakoma is a commercial software as far as i know. Have you asked the support of them? They should know!

Comment: Follow the instructions given here: http://www.bakoma-tex.com/menu/qa-answers.php?topic=20130221095615.txt